# ggplot2 Markdown in theme elements. Combining two columns to make one tick label with different fonts

Tags: r, ggplot2, markdown, ggtext

I am trying to apply this solution https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext to my data to create tick labels from a combination of two columns and apply different fonts to each. I think I've adapted the example code to my scenario but am getting this error after the mutate stage:

> > Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : object 'name' not found

Any pointers appreciated.

I'm looking for something like the below.

[image: ![Looking for something like the below.]

Here's the code I've tried:

```
df$Colour <- as.factor(df$Colour)
df$Number <- as.factor(df$Number)
df$Family <- factor(df$Family, levels = c("Ardeidae"))

df %>% mutate(
  name = glue("<i style={Comname} ({Sciname}</i>)"))%>%

ggplot(df[df$Value != 0,], aes(x=Sample, y=Number)) +
  geom_point(aes(size=Value, alpha = 0.9)) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels= name) +
  facet_grid(Family ~ Year, scales = "free", space = "free")
```

And some sample data.

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c("1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", 
"2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", 
"1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", 
"2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", 
"1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", "2017 - 2020", "1984 - 1989", 
"2017 - 2020"), Sample = c("Developed_zone_1992", "Developed_zone_2020", 
"Paddock_zone_1992", "Paddock_zone_2020", "Sanctuary_zone_1992", 
"Sanctuary_zone_2020", "Developed_zone_1992", "Developed_zone_2020", 
"Paddock_zone_1992", "Paddock_zone_2020", "Sanctuary_zone_1992", 
"Sanctuary_zone_2020", "Developed_zone_1992", "Developed_zone_2020", 
"Paddock_zone_1992", "Paddock_zone_2020", "Sanctuary_zone_1992", 
"Sanctuary_zone_2020", "Developed_zone_1992", "Developed_zone_2020", 
"Paddock_zone_1992", "Paddock_zone_2020", "Sanctuary_zone_1992", 
"Sanctuary_zone_2020"), Colour = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), 
    Value = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 0L, 5L), Family = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Ardeidae", class = "factor"), 
    Comname = c("47. Little egret", "47. Little egret", "47. Little egret", 
    "47. Little egret", "47. Little egret", "47. Little egret", 
    "46. Western great egret", "46. Western great egret", "46. Western great egret", 
    "46. Western great egret", "46. Western great egret", "46. Western great egret", 
    "45. Purple heron", "45. Purple heron", "45. Purple heron", 
    "45. Purple heron", "45. Purple heron", "45. Purple heron", 
    "44. Grey heron", "44. Grey heron", "44. Grey heron", "44. Grey heron", 
    "44. Grey heron", "44. Grey heron"), Sciname = c("Egretta garzetta", 
    "Egretta garzetta", "Egretta garzetta", "Egretta garzetta", 
    "Egretta garzetta", "Egretta garzetta", "Ardea alba", "Ardea alba", 
    "Ardea alba", "Ardea alba", "Ardea alba", "Ardea alba", "Ardea purpurea", 
    "Ardea purpurea", "Ardea purpurea", "Ardea purpurea", "Ardea purpurea", 
    "Ardea purpurea", "Ardea cinerea", "Ardea cinerea", "Ardea cinerea", 
    "Ardea cinerea", "Ardea cinerea", "Ardea cinerea"), Number = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("96", "97", "98", 
    "99"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image]

[image: Update]

Comment: Could you try this first: `#Data
df1 <- df %>% mutate(name = glue("<i style={Comname} ({Sciname}</i>)"))%>% filter(Value!=0)`

Comment: And then `ggplot(df1,aes(x=Sample, y=Number)) +geom_point(aes(size=Value, alpha = 0.9)) +scale_y_discrete(labels= df1$name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out by @Duck there are some minor issues in your code. Unfortunately these will not solve the `ggtext` issue

1. When you want to make use of markdown elements in `ggtext` you have to make use of `element_markdown` by setting e.g. `axis.text.y = element_markdown()` inside `theme()`.
2. To make the styling work you have to escape the point `.` in your Comname by the HTML entity `&#46;`. (The reason is that a number followed by a `.` marks the start of an ordered list in markdown.)
3. After these changes you don't need the `scale_y_discrete`. `ggplot2` will by default use `name` to label the ticks

```r
df$Colour <- as.factor(df$Colour)
df$Number <- as.factor(df$Number)
df$Family <- factor(df$Family, levels = c("Ardeidae"))

library(dplyr)
library(glue)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(
    Comname = stringr::str_replace(Comname, "\\.", "&#46;"),
    name = glue::glue("{Comname} <i>{Sciname}</i>")
  ) %>%
  filter(Value != 0) 

df1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sample, y = name)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = Value, alpha = 0.9)) +
  facet_grid(Family ~ Year, scales = "free", space = "free") +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_markdown())
```

[image]

Comment: That's amazing, thank you! The only issue I have now is that the ordering is not quite right (I've had a lot of trouble with this). I've added a new image to the questions. Can you help?

Comment: Hi @LisaB. According to the new image you want the categories to be in descending order, right? This could be achieved e.g. by making use of `forcats::fct_rev`. Try `ggplot(aes(x = Sample, y = forcats::fct_rev(name))) + ...`

Comment: Thanks @stefan. That works everywhere except for one group where the order is 100,101,102,99. This is the issue I was having before, and I had to create the Numbers column to get them all in the right order (or assigning the names as factors with levels which was very time consuming). Any thoughts?

Comment: (: Always forget about the "1xx". In that case `ggplot(aes(x = Sample, y = forcats::fct_reorder(name, desc(as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(Comname, "^\\d+"))))))`. 1. str_extract extracts the number at the beginning of the string,  2.  convert to numeric which 3. could be use inside fct_reorder to order the labels in descending order.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much.